# Bearer token authorization in a protected ASP.NET Core 2 MVC controller

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.1

We have an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project which uses IdentityServer4 to protect it's pages. The regular controllers redirect to identity server when not authenticated which is expected behaviour. What I'm trying to enable is having a public controller method be called by an non-signed in user using an access token, which is provided by the same identity server to the caller. If the user have a valid access token it the method should function regularly, if not give a 401 error or something like that.

The problem is, even when the method is called with a valid access token using `Authorization: Bearer` header it just gets redirected to IdentityServer. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? Do I have to define a different authorization scheme for this method or something?

Here's the OIDC config:

```
void oidcOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                options.Authority = openIdSettings.StsAuthority;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = openIdSettings.DiscoveryEndpointRequiresHttps;

                options.ClientId = openIdSettings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = openIdSettings.ClientSecret;

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                };

                options.Scope.Remove("profile");

                foreach (string scope in openIdSettings.Scopes)
                {
                    options.Scope.Add(scope.Trim());
                }
            }

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthenticationConstants.SigninScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(AuthenticationConstants.SigninScheme, oidcOptions);
```

Comment: Have you looked at mapping middleware to the path you're attempting to use in `Startup.cs` to bypass the identity server redirect?

Comment: @Tubs: Yes I have but the access token is provided by the same identity server so the public method path also needs to integrate with the identity server. I've seem to omitted that detail I've updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this adding new auth scheme using `AddJwtBearer("token_scheme"..)` as addition to the existing schemes and specifiying the auth scheme on the method using `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "token_scheme")]`.

Comment: Of note, you should really be using the new(ish) Policy stuff to handle your AuthN/AuthZ rules. [Policy-based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1)